Condensation in bathroom , need advice
I have a small bathroom, but with 4 of us in the house all showering each day, the moisture builds up, and the walls are dripping.im seeing mold appear and having to clean it off couple times a year , but it's getting worse .
The exterior wall always feels cold. There's 2 small windows. I have tried opening them wide but seems the steam stays in the room, I tried opening a smaller amount , but the same. Leaving the door open does help, but the teenager won't do that, and has hottest shower. I'm also worried steam will ruin other parts of the house.
The loft was converted to an office space so can't get an extractor in the bathroom ceiling easily.
Could we get one that goes through the exterior wall and is powered by the led light in the ceiling (we have 4 x spot lights)
Any other ideas to remove steam?

"The exterior wall always feels cold" strongly suggests that insulation is lacking there, which will exacerbate condensation.

Is it possible to get someone to do insulation filling. I know the front of the house has those small filled holes which suggests the previous owners did get the front done but not the back?

While insulating is usually always a good idea, in this case it would not remove any moisture, just keep it from forming into droplets.

And what's the bet way to stop it forming into droplets? An extractor? Or there's other ways? Should the window be left open or does this cause more colder air to come in and more moisture to be created?

Yes. You can definitely vent through the exterior wall at the top. It can be wired to your lights or on a separate switch. 50 CFM will probably do for a small bathroom but you may want more displacement. You'll want to insulate it and make sure it meets local codes.

Also make sure that replacement air can get into the bathroom from the house when blowing moist air out of the house - whether that be a vent down low, the typical door with a gap at the bottom, etc.

There's only a very small gap at bottom of door. Would leaving it open slightly be better? It wouldnt pull air in from outside of window is open?

You can get through-the-wall fans, but perhaps a dehumidifier on a timer or humidistat switch could help you out too.

Here is a link to a unit I have installed in a rental property. It works very well.  https://www.amazon.com/Broan-512M-Through-Wall-6-Inch-Sones/dp/B000LNKUN8/ref=asc_df_B000LNKUN8?mcid=16b3d2ae1038345d82c52ffbf88306ed&tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=693345907102&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=9284038298742141645&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9012306&hvtargid=pla-384254769736&psc=1

Thanks, do you know if this could be powered via the led ceiling light driver? Or off the cable? Very limited access though. Only via the lights own hole, can't get to it from the top as flooring is down.

You want to power it with 120VAC. So you want to wire it in line before the driver.
